# How to design filters/interceptors in Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux

While migrating my project from Spring MVC architechture to the Webflux framework, I encountered some confusion. I want to understand what are the corresponding equivalents (if any) or alternatives of the configurations used to perform Authorization/Form Validation in MVC, that will apply for WebFlux ?

Comment: your question is too broad; you can configure `ExchangeFilterFunction` on the `WebClient.Builder` itself, but I don't know if that's what you're looking for. Please rephrase your question with a more focused use case.

Comment: One way if you are using functional model is to use WebFilter to have your application cross cutting concern. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978794/enable-cors-in-spring-5-webflux to enable CORS at one place which intercepts all requests.