# Enable CORS in Spring 5 Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, cors, spring-webflux

How to enable **CORS** in a Spring 5 Webflux Project?

I cannot find any proper documentation.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/cors.html

Comment: have you tried @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") on your controller?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is another solution with the Webflux Configurer.

Side Note: Its Kotlin Code (copied from my project) but you can easily translate that to Java Code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
class WebConfig: WebFluxConfigurer
{
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry)
    {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*") // any host or put domain(s) here
            .allowedMethods("GET, POST") // put the http verbs you want allow
            .allowedHeaders("Authorization") // put the http headers you want allow
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the only solution I see to this problem, but it's not working for me. the header simply is not added to the response. this overridden method is called as seen with the debugger. did you have any other config besides this?

Comment: Doesn't work when using Spring Hateoas and @EnableHypermediaSupport - links are not added anymore after extending from WebFluxConfigurer.

Answer (score 44):

I had success with this custom filter:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsUtils;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;


@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

  private static final String ALLOWED_HEADERS = "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN";
  private static final String ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS";
  private static final String ALLOWED_ORIGIN = "*";
  private static final String MAX_AGE = "3600";

  @Bean
  public WebFilter corsFilter() {
    return (ServerWebExchange ctx, WebFilterChain chain) -> {
      ServerHttpRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
      if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = ctx.getResponse();
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",ALLOWED_HEADERS);
        if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
          response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
          return Mono.empty();
        }
      }
      return chain.filter(ctx);
    };
  }

}
```

and `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` should not be included as dependency - filter does not work with it.

Comment: For non-functional model in Spring WebFlux what is the recommended way to achieve filter like functionality if using Netty and no classical servlet filters and not using functional model filters like above ?

Comment: @ROCKY, i had checked this example in netty - it worked. I think you can use non-functional model in controllers and it will work(however haven`t tried it).

Comment: in netty, this is not working for me. OPTIONS still throwing CORS faillure

Comment: Thank you for this answer, It saved my day. I Found this link on https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/112

Answer (score 9):

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebFluxConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebFluxConfigurerComposite() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

which corresponds to:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
```

for spring mvc.

Comment: I have tryied your answer with spring-cloud-starter-gateway(it use spring 5 webflux) - no success

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Dachstein, replacing WebMvc configs with Webflux is the correct way of adding global CORS Config here.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CORSConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone wants a Kotlin version of Zufar's answer(works like a charm with webflux routing functions) without additionally figuring out how Kotlin's SAM conversions work, here is the code:

```
@Bean
fun corsFilter(): WebFilter {
    return WebFilter { ctx, chain ->
        val request = ctx.request
        if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)) {
            val response = ctx.response
            val headers = response.headers
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGIN)
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS)
            headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE)
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ALLOWED_HEADERS)
            if (request.method === HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
                response.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
                return@WebFilter Mono.empty<Void>()
            }
        }
        chain.filter(ctx)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
As I started testing it I found one problem with this solution. It's Ok if you really want to allow all methods. But imagine you want to only allow `POST` and `OPTIONS`, for example. And the browser is trying to send `PUT`.

Then a preflight response will basically say "hey, I can only serve POST and OPTIONS, but my HTTP status will be `OK` if you give me a request with `Access-Control-Request-Method=PUT`". It should be `403 Forbidden` however.
What's more, most of those headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` should only be added to preflight requests, not all `CORS` requests.
Solution:

```
@Bean
fun corsWebFilter(): CorsWebFilter {
    val corsConfig = CorsConfiguration()
    corsConfig.allowedOrigins = Arrays.asList(ALLOWED_ORIGINS)
    corsConfig.maxAge = MAX_AGE.toLong()
    //Notice it's singular. Can't be comma separated list
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(ALLOWED_METHOD)
    corsConfig.addAllowedHeader(ALLOWED_HEADER)

    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    source.registerCorsConfiguration(MATCH_ALL_PATH_SEGMENTS, corsConfig)

    return CorsWebFilter(source)
}
```

where

```
const val MATCH_ALL_PATH_SEGMENTS = "/**"
```

Answer (score 2):

While @Dachstein's answer is correct it still may not work if you have Security enabled. You can read the documentation about this here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors but the provided code may not be enough because of missing `applyPermitDefaultValues()` method.

If so, try the code below:

```java
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8081"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: This one worked for me with cors auth enabled. Just added one extra line for headers
`configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the official documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-cors

There are 3 main options

1) Using the @CrossOrigin annotation on a rest controller - it can be used at class and/or method level

2) Implement the addCorsMapping method from the WebFluxConfigurer - it gives you an hook into the global CorsRegistry object

3) Define a CorsWebFilter component - good choice for functional endpoints

Please look at the docs, are well explained.

Personally I use the third option when I want to allow cors while developing and I have decoupled the backend from the frontend module.

Imagine that you have webflux on a backend module while on the frontend you have a react or angular app. While developing the frontend features you might want to use webpack-dev-server for hot reloading while still running the backend on netty - the port will be different and this will cause CORS problem. With the third option you can easily link the @Component to @Profile("dev") so that when you deploy in prod CORS are enabled.

Comment: You can easily get around your webpack-dev-server port vs netty port problem by using a proxy.  See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy. There is no CORS needed then. If I understood your problem correctly?

Comment: @gtuz, are you sure you used spring-gateway? None of your options work for me

Answer (score 1):

If using spring webflux security following snippet works

```
protected ServerHttpSecurity applyCors(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.cors().configurationSource(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()).and();
}

private UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
    // corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource ccs = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    ccs.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return ccs;
}
```