# How do you handle adding a CORS header in a Spring Boot server with graphql-kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cors, graphql-kotlin

I am building a simple Spring Server project using the [GraphQL Kotlin library](https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/graphql-kotlin) created & open-sourced by Expedia. I have a backend up and running, talking to the datastore, and I'm able to fetch data by sending queries via Playground.

When I try to connect from my React frontend (using Apollo), the initial OPTIONS request gets a 404 response due to a CORS issue. I am relatively new to Spring Boot and there are a lot of potential approaches documented on SO and elsewhere.

How do I intercept the response & add the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many of the aforementioned approaches, I found one that worked for my particular combination of variables.

These, for example, did not work:

1. WebFluxConfigurer component that overrides the `addCorsMappings`
   function
2. `@CrossOrigin` annotation on the query function
3. Add the spring boot actuator lib to the project and add management.endpoints.web.cors config to the application.yml, per [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-cors)

What ultimately did work for me was a custom WebFilter subclass, per this SO question: [Enable CORS in Spring 5 Webflux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978794/enable-cors-in-spring-5-webflux)

and also [this tutorial](https://www.roytuts.com/spring-boot-functional-reactive-programming/), which illuminated a lot about how Spring Boot works in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
 @Bean
    @Profile("!production")
    fun corsFilter(): CorsWebFilter = CorsWebFilter(
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource().apply {
            registerCorsConfiguration(
                "/**",
                CorsConfiguration().apply {
                    allowCredentials = true
                    allowedOrigins = listOf("*")
                    allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
                    allowedMethods = listOf("*")
                }
            )
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

For me (using same technologies like you), creating custom filter component (CorsFilter) worked the best out of all other options:

Example of my configuration:

```
@Component
class CorsFilter: WebFilter {

    @Value("\${cors.allowed_origin}")
    lateinit var allowedOrigin: String

    override fun filter(ctx: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        ctx.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigin)
        ctx.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS")
        ctx.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        ctx.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range, Authorization")
        return when {
            ctx.request.method == HttpMethod.OPTIONS -> {
                ctx.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
                ctx.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT
                Mono.empty()
            }
            else -> {
                ctx.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range")
                chain.filter(ctx)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

note: `allowedOrigin` variable is taken from applications.properties files

Answer (score 0):

Only adding the next configuration in spring boot-kotlin server work with React and Apollo:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsUtils
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

@Configuration
class ReactiveConfigurations {

    companion object {
        const val ALLOWED_HEADERS = "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN"
        const val ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        const val ALLOWED_ORIGIN = "*"
        const val MAX_AGE = "3600"
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsFilter(): WebFilter {
        return WebFilter { ctx, chain ->
            val request = ctx.request
            if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)) {
                val response = ctx.response
                val headers = response.headers
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGIN)
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS)
                headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE)
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ALLOWED_HEADERS)
                if (request.method === HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
                    response.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
                    return@WebFilter Mono.empty<Void>()
                }
            }
            chain.filter(ctx)
        }
    }
}
```