# Spring Boot Webflux - Security CORS is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I cannot seem to get CORS working right in Spring Boot's Webflux - here is my config and no matter what I do I get CORS errors with a VUE client:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class HelloWebfluxSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val configuration = CorsConfiguration()
        configuration.allowedOrigins = listOf("http://localhost:8080")
        configuration.allowedMethods = listOf("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
        return source
    }

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): MapReactiveUserDetailsService {
        val user: UserDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("user")
            .roles("USER")
            .build()
        return MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user)
    }

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http
            .authorizeExchange { exchanges: AuthorizeExchangeSpec ->
                exchanges
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            }
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

I've tried `cors().configurationSource(withDefaults())` too (which should use the configuration source bean I've defined, according to the docs.

What do I need to do to make this work?

EDIT: Here's my browser error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8088/data/configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 3):

So, it turns out that I needed to add:

`configuration.allowedHeaders = listOf("*")`

Anybody that's having problems with this can add this to `application.properties` to see the exact reason that the request is rejected (or set your debugger to debug in the `DefaultCorsProcessor` class) and watch what happens:

`logging.level.org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.DefaultCorsProcessor=debug`

> > ... o.s.w.c.reactive.DefaultCorsProcessor    : Reject: headers '[authorization]' are not allowed

Answer (score -1):

In Rest controller you could do this:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

for webflux look at this:
[Enable CORS in Spring 5 Webflux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978794/enable-cors-in-spring-5-webflux)

Comment: That does not work with Security on...